# problems while i receiving data from socket. React and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io

I have some problems while i receiving data from socket.

```
const [counter,setCounter]=useState(0)

      useEffect(() => {

        if (socket == null) return
          const spin = (dat) => {
            if (dat !== '') {
               console.log(counter)
          }
          socket.on("receive-spin", spin)
        

      },[socket])
```

When I change `counter -> 2` from another part of code and then again call this socket it will `console log -> 0`.

I don't know why it is like that because it "refreshes" because `console log` is still showing but with first value.

Comment: The `setCounter` is what modifies the state (i.e., counter), at which point `useEffect` side effect is triggered. Make sure you're calling `setCounter(value)` at appropriate event handler such as onClick.

Comment: yes i do. And still doesnt work ;c

Answer (score 1):

it seems like the issue is with the closure of the spin function that you are passing to the socket.on method.

The spin function is defined inside the useEffect hook and references the counter state variable through its closure. However, since counter is not included as a dependency of the useEffect hook, the spin function will continue to reference the initial value of counter (which is 0) even if it changes elsewhere in your code.

To fix this, you can add counter as a dependency of the useEffect hook, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (socket == null) return;
  const spin = (dat) => {
    if (dat !== '') {
      console.log(counter);
    }
  };
  socket.on("receive-spin", spin);
  return () => {
    socket.off("receive-spin", spin);
  };
}, [socket, counter]);
```

This way, the useEffect hook will re-run whenever counter changes, causing a new spin function to be created with the updated value of counter.

Note that I also added a cleanup function to remove the spin event listener when the component unmount. This is important to prevent memory leaks.